# Input Shape in Keras Autoencoder

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

i'm trying to train an autoencoder in the following code:

```
encoder_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(x_Train.shape[1]), name='img')
encoder_out = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = "relu")(encoder_input)

encoder = keras.Model(encoder_input, encoder_out, name="encoder")

decoder_input = keras.layers.Dense(602896, activation = "relu")(encoder_out)
decoder_output = keras.layers.Reshape((769, 28, 28))(decoder_input)

opt = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=1e-3)

autoencoder = keras.Model(encoder_input, decoder_output, name = "autoencoder")
autoencoder.summary()

autoencoder.compile(opt, loss='mse')
autoencoder.fit(x_Train, x_Train, epochs=10, batch_size=64, validation_split = 0.1)
```

However, it returns the error:

```
tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 28) for input 
KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 28), dtype=tf.float32, name='img'), name='img', 
description="created by layer 'img'"), but it was called on an input with 
incompatible shape (None, 28, 28).
```

I don't know how to deal with that or to resize my input.  My x_train is a vector with size [769,28,28]

How to handle the error?

[That's the summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62QGC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your input shape for your autoencoder is a little weird, your training data has a shaped of 28x28, with 769 as your batch, so the fix should be like this:

```py
encoder_input = keras.layer.Input(shape=(28, 28), name='img')
encoder_out = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = "relu")(encoder_input)

# For ur decoder, you need to change a bit as well
decoder_input = keras.layers.Dense(784, activation = "sigmoid")(encoder_out) # Flatten until 28x28 =784
decoder_output = keras.layers.Reshape((28, 28))(decoder_input) # From there reshape back to 28x28
```

Comment: I still got an error, specified in the answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem (apart from the wrong shape in the input layer (has to be `shape=(28, 28)` and the output layer (has to be `(28,28)`) like in [Edwin Cheong 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67113996/20068036)) is that you forgot a flatten layer after your input layer. This leads to the incompatible shape.

Adapted the answer from [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67113996/20068036):

```
encoder_input = keras.layer.Input(shape=(28, 28), name='img')
encoder_input = keras.layer.Flatten()(encoder_input)
encoder_out = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = "relu")(encoder_input)

decoder_input = keras.layers.Dense(784, activation = "sigmoid")(encoder_out) 
decoder_output = keras.layers.Reshape((28, 28))(decoder_input)
```